# How can i use soft assertion in Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, assertion

I have configured soft assert from npm  (npm i soft-assert) and now my package.josn has "soft-assert": "^0.2.3"

i want to use function of Soft assert

```
softAssert(actual, expected, msg, ignoreKeys)
```

But don't know, what is the exact steps to use it

Example:
When i use soft assertion function in my code, getting following error.

If i use like this

1. cy.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch and will execute next line")  : not supported
   or if i use different way like
2. softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch and will execute next line") : SoftAssert not defined

Can any one tell me how to use this 'softAssert' function in cypress code with some small example?

---

Now the problem I am facing

```
it('asserts and logs and fails', () => { 
  Cypress.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch..."); 
  cy.log("text") 
  Cypress.softAssertAll(); 
})
```

I need my code after soft assertion as `cy.log("text")` to be executed in the same 'it' block but the current test failing the whole 'it' block, without executing 'cy.log("text")' statement.

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868107/does-cypress-support-soft-assertion/55879165#55879165

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used it but some how wait and data retrieving from fixture file variable functionalities failed. Is there any other way, i can use it without adding anything in my index.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The soft assertion concept is pretty cool, and you can add it with minimal implementation to Cypress

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

it('asserts several times and only fails at the end', () => {
  jsonAssertion.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch");
  // some more assertions, not causing a failure

  jsonAssertion.softAssertAll();  // Now fail the test if above fails
})
```

To me, it would be nicer to see each soft assertion failure in the log, so it's possible to add custom commands to wrap the soft-assert functions

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

Cypress.Commands.add('softAssert', (actual, expected, message) => {
  jsonAssertion.softAssert(actual, expected, message)
  if (jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.length) {
    jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.forEach(diff => {

      const log = Cypress.log({
        name: 'Soft assertion error',
        displayName: 'softAssert',
        message: diff.error.message
      })
    
    })
  }
});
Cypress.Commands.add('softAssertAll', () => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll())


//-- all above can go into /cypress/support/index.js
//-- to save adding it to every test (runs once each test session)



it('asserts and logs but does not fail', () => {
  cy.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch...");
  cy.log('text');    // this will run
})

it('asserts and logs and fails', () => {
  cy.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch...");
  cy.log('text');    // this will run

  cy.softAssertAll();
})
```

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for the info 

Now the problem i am facing 

it('asserts and logs and fails', () => {
  Cypress.softAssert(10, 12, "expected actual mismatch and will execute next line");
   cy.log("text")
  Cypress.softAssertAll();
})

i need my code after soft assertion as cy.log("text") to be executed in the same 'it' block but the current test faling the whole 'it' block, whithout executing 'cy.log("text")' statement.

Comment: My eyes are spinning, so I added that to the question.

Comment: I see the problem, the `Cypress.softAssert()` function is synchronous in the test, but commands like `cy.log()` are queued and asynchronous (so the test ends before they can execute).

Comment: Also, the log message from `Cypress.softAssertAll()` seems too much. I'll see if it can be done better.

Comment: It works better as a custom command, small changes made to the code above (`cy` not `Cypress`).

Comment: Great it works, Thanks. Now only problem is the assertion error is so lengthy and if we can get some one liner it will be great.

Comment: I can check that tomorrow, but you might figure it out - take a look at properties of `jsonAssertion` inside  `Cypress.Commands.add('softAssertAll', () => `, something there may be useful to `cy.log()`.

Comment: Hello, I can't add these soft assertion Cypress commands to my project. 

I use cypress 10.4 my project has index.js, e2e.js, and commands.js

Is there any more detailed example about how to implement soft assertion code into cypress version +10?