# How can I imlement soft Assertion in my Cypress test

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am struggling with implementing soft assertions in my Cypress test.
I need to convert all the assertions to soft assertions. The problem I encounter is that I cannot locate the element in the jsonAssertion. For example **cy.get('span[class="h4"]')** is the element and I need to assert that it contains some text. How can this be done with **jsonAssertion.softAssert()**?

This is my test:

```
describe('Load Validation Test', function(){
  const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

  it('Load Validation Test', function(){
      let url = Cypress.config().baseUrl
      
      cy.visit(url+'activityTaskManagement')

      cy.get('span[class="h4"]').should('contain.text','Manage Activities')
      cy.get('button[ng-click="vm.addActivityTask();"]').should('be.visible')
      cy.get('button[ng-click="vm.addActivityTaskBulk();"]').should('be.visible')
      cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').should('be.visible')
      cy.get('div table[class="table table-striped b-t b-light table-nowrap"]').should('be.visible')
      
  })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For soft-assert, see [How can i use soft assertion in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66133161/16997707)

As custom commands,

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

Cypress.Commands.add('softAssert', (actual, expected, message) => {
  jsonAssertion.softAssert(actual, expected, message)
  if (jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.length) {
    jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.forEach(diff => {

      const log = Cypress.log({
        name: 'Soft assertion error',
        displayName: 'softAssert',
        message: diff.error.message
      })
    
    })
  }
});
Cypress.Commands.add('softAssertAll', () => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll())
```

In the test

```js
cy.get('span[class="h4"]').then($el=> {
  const actual = $el.text()
  cy.softAssert(actual, 'Manage Activities')
})
```

Comment: I like the custom logging message.

Comment: But the proxy idea is worth looking at too - seems like simpler syntax.

Answer (score 5):

There's also package that proxies `expect`

```js
const { proxy, flush } = require("@alfonso-presa/soft-assert");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const softExpect = proxy(expect);

cy.get('span[class="h4"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should(actual => {
    softExpect(actual).to.eq('Manage Activities')
  })

flush()   // Now fail the test if above fails
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to assert that the element `span[class="h4"]` has some text you can do:

```js
cy.get('span[class="h4"]').should('include.text','Manage Activities')
```

Using soft assert you can do something like this:

```js
const jsonAssertion = require('soft-assert')

describe('Load Validation Test', function () {
  it('Load Validation Test', function () {
    let url = Cypress.config().baseUrl
    cy.visit(url + 'activityTaskManagement')

    cy.get('span[class="h4"]')
      .invoke(text)
      .then((text) => {
        jsonAssertion.softContains(
          text,
          'Manage Activities',
          'Some custom message'
        )
      })

    cy.get('button[ng-click="vm.addActivityTask();"]').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('button[ng-click="vm.addActivityTaskBulk();"]').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').should('be.visible')
    cy.get(
      'div table[class="table table-striped b-t b-light table-nowrap"]'
    ).should('be.visible')
  })
})
```

Comment: I need to use soft Assert with jsonAssertion.softAssert()