# Soft assert or something similar in Cypress

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, chai, assertion

At the end of my test, I'm verifying multiple values to see if they're correctly captured in the form. I'm using expect statements. I realized if one expect fails, rest will not execute.
All these verification are part of a single test case. I do want my test case to be marked as fail even if one expect fails but would like all the expect statements to be executed. So I can't really separate them. Is there an alternative? Do soft assertions work for Cypress?

```js
verifyRoledetails(testobject) {

    cy.contains('h3','Role details').nextUntil('button').should(($roledetails)=> {

    expect($roledetails.children('label').get(0).innerText).to.eq('Role title');
    expect($roledetails.children('p').get(0).innerText).to.eq(testobject.role_details.title);

    expect($roledetails.children('label').get(1).innerText).to.eq('Where is the role based');
    expect($roledetails.children('p').get(1).innerText).to.eq(testobject.role_details.role_basedat);

 })
};
```

Comment: You can check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868107/does-cypress-support-soft-assertion

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check this.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer, which gives a straight-forward way using package [soft-assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-assert)

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

verifyRoledetails(testobject) {

  cy.contains('h3','Role details').nextUntil('button')
    .should(($roledetails)=> {

      const label1Text = $roledetails.children('label').get(0).innerText;
      jsonAssertion.softAssert(label1Text, 'Role title');

      const p1Text = $roledetails.children('p').get(0).innerText;
      jsonAssertion.softAssert(p1Text, testobject.role_details.title);

      const label2Text = $roledetails.children('label').get(1).innerText;
      jsonAssertion.softAssert(label2Text, 'Where is the role based');

      const p2Text = $roledetails.children('p').get(1).innerText;
      jsonAssertion.softAssert(p2Text, testobject.role_details.role_basedat);

      jsonAssertion.softAssertAll();  // Now fail the test if above fails
    })
})
```

But that's a bit of a flip-flop in terms of format.

To stick with the `expect().matcher()` pattern, try [@alfonso-presa/soft-assert](https://github.com/alfonso-presa/soft-assert)

```js
const { proxy, flush } = require("@alfonso-presa/soft-assert");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const softExpect = proxy(expect);

verifyRoledetails(testobject) {

  cy.contains('h3','Role details').nextUntil('button')
    .should(($roledetails)=> {

      const label1Text = $roledetails.children('label').get(0).innerText;
      softExpect(label1Text).to.eq('Role title');

      const p1Text = $roledetails.children('p').get(0).innerText;
      softExpect(p1Text).to.eq(testobject.role_details.title);

      const label2Text = $roledetails.children('label').get(1).innerText;
      softExpect(label2Text).to.eq('Where is the role based');

      const p2Text = $roledetails.children('p').get(1).innerText;
      softExpect(p2Text).to.eq(testobject.role_details.role_basedat);

      flush()   // Now fail the test if above fails
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank for taking time to respond to my query. I'll try this.