# How can I make `.only` and `this` to work after hacking the Cypress hook?

Tags: cypress

I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55879165/7244337) to do the things I need after the test is finished which run before the `after` and `afterEach` hook. But there're 2 problems:

1. The `.only` doesn't work.
2. The `this` doesn't work also.

As you may know, if there's any error occurs at `afterEach`, Cypress will skip the rest test cases. Please advise me :)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Copy this to `cypress/support/index.js`

```
// monkey-patch `it` callback so we insert `cy.then()` as a last command
// to each test case
function itCallback(title, func) {
  func();
  cy.then(() => {
    //do my stuffs here 
  });
}

const origIt = window.it;
window.it = (title, func) => {
  origIt(title, func && (() => itCallback(title, func)));
};
window.it.only = (title, func) => {
  origIt.only(title, func && (() => itCallback(title, func)));
};
window.it.skip = (title, func) => {
  origIt.skip(title, func);
};
```

2. Run this test case to see `.only` error:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Test', () => {

  it.only('Should run this only.', () => {
    cy.log("only")
  });

  it('Should skip this.', () => {
    cy.log("skip")
  });

});
```

3. Run this test case to see `this` is undefined:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Test', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.wrap("test").as("test");
  })

  it('test', function () {
    cy.log('' + this.test)
  });

});
```

4. Remove the code block at step 1 and see 2 test cases execute normally.

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish after a test finishes and a before `after()` and `afterEach()`?

Comment: for example: do soft assertions. If you put the assertAll() at `afterEach()` it will skip all the rest test cases if assertAll() throw error. If you put the assertAll() at the end of the test case, it will be ignored when there's a Cypress error that occurs before.

Comment: `it.only` using the monkey patch from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868107/does-cypress-support-soft-assertion works with Cypress 3.8.0 and thereafter it is broken. In Cypress 9.7.0 I get the error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parent')`.

I posted also about this in the original post which suggested the monkey patch.

Comment: I found a related issue in the Cypress GitHub issue list under ["this" context doesn't work as expected in one of my repos](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17300). There is a comment which says: "This happens because you overwrite `it` global function but fail to preserve the context by using `=>` instead of function syntax. ... You should use the `function` syntax and be careful how you call the overwritten functions ...". I've asked if the issue submitter could post the corrected code.

Comment: Great!!! Hope the code from the issue submitter could resolve our issue.

Comment: There is a suggested solution for `it.only` in github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/23280. This has not yet been confirmed though.

Comment: that's my suggestion :) I made an executable example on github: https://github.com/lehoanglu0ng/cypress-only